# Big ArrayCollection and Doctrine (symfony2)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, arraycollection

I use Symfony for my website but I have a problem with the performance, I have a big ArrayCollection ( +50000 elements), in my doctrine query I did the differents joins but the page is too long to load. How I can optimise the loading of the page?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to load all the data in a single page? A list of data that long would normally be paged (e.g using query->setFirstResult() / query->setMaxResults()) and provide facilities for filtering the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to not load everything on a single page. Use pagination.

Good choice is [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle).